# grid having square cells of fixed size independent of the content

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a rectangular grid (5 rows, 4 columns) on a A4 paper. All cells have the dimension 5cm by 5cm. For this I use a table as can be seen from the code. This table can fit on the paper by shifting it a way bit to the left and upwards. The size of the cells is fixed and has to stay like that independent of the content which can be a picture or several lines of text created using the \makecell command. My attempt is given but it does not work for the height of the cells, this keeps on changing. What am I doing wrong?

best regards, Dimitri

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\graphicspath{{./}{./Pictures/}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

  \begin{table}
    \begin{center}
      \vspace*{-2.5cm}
      \hspace*{-3.25cm}
      \begin{tabular}{|m{5cm}|m{5cm}|m{5cm}|m{5cm}|}
        \hline
        \centering{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=4.5cm,keepaspectratio]{Stanford_Bunny}} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}\\[5cm]
        \hline
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}\\[5cm]
        \hline
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1}} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1}} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1}} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1}}\\[5cm]
        \hline
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}\\[5cm]
        \hline
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6} &
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}\\[5cm]
        \hline
      \end{tabular}%
    \end{center}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output is as follows (the last column is also behaving bad):

[image: example]

Comment: [How to specify a fixed height for all rows in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12761/134144)  might be interesting.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Please edit you question, leave out your answer and post it separately.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I adapted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two possibilities

Below, I describe two different solution

1. Using tabular, [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array), [hhline](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) etc.
2. Using the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals)

I have included the code for a `calstable` at the end of the answer, but since the output is the same for both solution, I have not included a picture of the result.

### tabular and friends

The first possibility is to add a ‘phantom’ column with an invisible, vertical rule of 5 cm in a tabular. I have defined a new column type doing this. Since you have four columns of equal width, I defined them as a new column type, too. Then I can add the necessary commands to centre the content horizontally only one place.

Be ware that the width of your tabular *is not* 20 cm. You have to add the width of the five vertical rules (`arrayrulewidth` standard is 0.4pt, *i.e.* 2 pt). Therefore, I had to change the left and right margin of your MWE to get rid of an `overfull hbox` message. It is similar for the height, it is 25 cm + 6 `arrayrulewidth`.

*EDIT 20190807:* To ensure that the tabular is vertically and horizontally centred on the page based on the paper size (not the margins), I have enclosed the table in a new environment, which is based on [Andrew Swann’s answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154736/9632).

To have exactly `0.9cm` space between the rows, which you mentioned in a comment, I ‘cheated’ and added double vertical rules (`\hline\hline`) between the rows and increased the space between the two rules to `0.9cm minus two \arrayrulewidth`s. To avoid a blank first page, I decreased all document margins to `0cm`.

```
\usepackage[left=0cm,top=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry} % Zero margin
\setlength\doublerulesep{\dimexpr(0.9cm-(2\arrayrulewidth))} % Increased space between horizontal rules
```

You had enclosed your tabular in an floating environment, but this type of full page tabular should not float.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, demo]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array, hhline}

\usepackage[left=0cm,top=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}


%% This code is modified from Andrew Swann's code in this answer
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154736/9632

\newenvironment{preface}{\clearpage\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}%
  \newgeometry{margin=0cm,ignoreheadfoot}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \centering%
  \vspace*{\fill}\nointerlineskip\small}%
  {\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage\restoregeometry}


%\graphicspath{{./}{./Pictures/}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0cm}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\rule{0pt}{5cm}}m{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{preface}
\setlength\doublerulesep{\dimexpr(0.9cm-(2\arrayrulewidth))}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|M}|@{}F@{}}
\hline
\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=4.5cm,keepaspectratio]{bunny}
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&\\
\hline\hline
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&\\
\hline\hline
\textbf{line 1}
&
\textbf{line 1}
&
\textbf{line 1}
&
\textbf{line 1}
&\\
\hline\hline
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&\\
\hline\hline
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&
\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6
&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\par
\end{preface}
\end{document}
```

### calstable

In my opinion, the package cals is better suited for this type of tabular because it is so easy to fix the width and height of the columns and rows. However, using ‘phantom’ lines also works in cals.

The 0.9cm space between rows, are easily fixed by additional rows of that height.

In cals, the command `\cals@setpadding{<wd>}` is the equivalent to `tabcolsep`, but it also sets the distance between rows. Since rules (borders) are phantoms, I have set the padding to `0.3pt`, which should result in cells 5cmx5cm inside.

The commands `\alignC` centre the cell content horizontally, and works until it is switch off by another alignment command. `\vfil` centre the cell content vertically, and can be set globally by defining the command `cals@AtBeginCell`, i.e. `\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil}` (you may also use `\newcommand*` or `\renewcommand*`).

Also have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, demo]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{cals}

\usepackage[left=0cm,top=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}

%% This code is modified from Andrew Swann's code in this answer
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154736/9632
\newenvironment{preface}{\clearpage\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}%
  \newgeometry{margin=0cm,ignoreheadfoot}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vspace*{\fill}\nointerlineskip\small}%
  {\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage\restoregeometry}

%\graphicspath{{./}{./Pictures/}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{preface}
\begin{calstable}[c]                         % Centre the calstable
% Defining 4 equal columns
\colwidths{{5cm}{5cm}{5cm}{5cm}
    }

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.3pt}     % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.03pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.3pt}
\cals@setpadding{0.3pt}            % To ensure that the inside of cell is 5 cm
\def\cals@cs@width{0.3pt}          % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.3pt}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax    % Right Border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0.0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax    % Left Border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0.0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}

\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil}       % Vertically centre content of all cell
%\def\cals@AtEndCell{}

%% Start of tabular body, no header row
% R1B1
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=4.5cm,keepaspectratio]{bunny}}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \ht\cals@current@row=5cm
\erow
% R2B1b   %% Fore creating space between rows
\brow
   \lb\rb\cell{}                                  % \lb&\rb  -  shortcuts for tuning off left and right border this row
   \cell{}
   \cell{}
   \cell{}\lb\rb                                   % use shortcuts for tuning on left and right border for next row
    \ht\cals@current@row=0.9cm
\erow
%R3B2
\brow
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \ht\cals@current@row=5cm
\erow
% R4B2b
\brow
   \lb\rb\cell{}
   \cell{}
   \cell{}
   \cell{}\lb\rb
    \ht\cals@current@row=0.9cm
\erow
%R5B3
\brow
    \cell{\textbf{line 1}}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1}}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1}}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1}}
    \ht\cals@current@row=5cm
\erow
% R6B3b
\brow
   \lb\rb\cell{}
   \cell{}
   \cell{}
   \cell{}\lb\rb
    \ht\cals@current@row=0.9cm
\erow
%R7B4
\brow
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \ht\cals@current@row=5cm
\erow
% R8B4b
\brow
   \lb\rb\cell{}
   \cell{}
   \cell{}
   \cell{}\lb\rb
    \ht\cals@current@row=0.9cm
\erow
%R2B5
\brow
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \cell{\textbf{line 1} \par line 2 \par line 3 \par line 4 \par line 5 \par line 6}
    \ht\cals@current@row=5cm
\erow
\end{calstable}\par
\end{preface}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. The one thing that puzzles me is the fact that you have adapted the "space" to be used horizontally to 0.46cm but not for the height. Shouldn't this be adapted as well according to your remark on this or is there a reason for not having to do this?

Comment: I understand what you mean but isn't there a small error in the numbers? The height of A4 is 29.7cm minus the 4.7cm I subtracted for bottom and top gives a remaining space of 25.0cm which was the 5x5cm for the squares. That was the initial intend for this. However if I understand correctly it is in reality a little bit off due to the horizontal lines. How should it be corrected? Setting the 4.7cm to a smaller value in order to have enough space or in a different manner?

Comment: @Dimitri You are absolutely right. I have updated the code with a new environment that ensure horizontal and vertical centring based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154736/9632) from Andrew Swann.

Comment: Many thanks, this is perfect. Assume that I would want a gap between the rows of p.e. 0.9cm, would it be difficult to implement this? This additional requirement was raised after carefully checking the application and was not known in the beginning.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I just do not see the 4.5cm, is it possible that it should be 4*0.9cm=3.6cm, or am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 2):

After 11 hours of searching I have obtained a solution which I would like to share. The code is fairly easy to follow and the essence is a minipage environment inside a table. Note that only using the first column in this minipage set-up does the trick but I kept it for all cells due to ease of recognising what I did later on. Note also that the margins of the "pagespace" that can be used is adapted to fit the grid as wanted. Presumably there are shorter ways of doing this repeated minipage typing but I don't know how this is done. Hope this is helpful for someone.

best regards, Dimitri

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,top=2.35cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=2.35cm]{geometry}

\graphicspath{{./}{./Pictures/}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{tabular}{|m{5cm}|m{5cm}|m{5cm}|m{5cm}|}
    \hline
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=4.5cm,keepaspectratio]{Bunny}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage}\\
    \hline
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage}\\
    \hline
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1}}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1}}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1}}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1}}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage}\\
    \hline
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage}\\
    \hline
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage} &
      \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}
        \begin{center}
        \makecell{\textbf{line 1} \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\ line 4 \\ line 5 \\ line 6}
        \end{center}
      \end{minipage}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output looks now as follows:

[image]